# How to input text containing less than 1000 words with spaces and punctuations?

Tags: c++, string

I am able to input string using the following code:

```
string str;
getline(cin, str);
```

But I want to know how to put an upper limit on the number of words that can be given as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you are asking with just `getline` or even `read`. If you want to limit the number of words you can use a simple `for` loop and the stream in operator.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string word;
    std::vector<std::string> words;

    for (size_t count = 0;  count < 1000 && std::cin >> word; ++count)
        words.push_back(word);
}
```

This will read up to 1000 words and stuff them into a vector.

Answer (score 0):

`getline()` reads characters and has no notion of what a *word* is. The definition of a word is likely to change with context and language. You'll need to read a stream one character at a time, extracting *words* that match your definition of a word and stop when you have met your limit.

Comment: By word, I mean simple english words. Words can be counted by using spaces between them.

Comment: Ok, define `std::string word;` and you can read a string delimited by whitespace with `cin >> word`. The just loop for as many as you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can either read one character at a time, or only process 1000 characters from your string(s).

You may be able to set a limit on std::string and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this program helps you out. This code handles input ofmultiple words in a single line as well

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int LIMIT = 5;
    int counter = 0;
    string line;
    string words[LIMIT];
    bool flag = false;
    char* word;
    do
    {
        cout<<"enter a word or a line";
        getline(cin,line);
        word = strtok(const_cast<char*>(line.c_str())," ");
        while(word)
        {
            if(LIMIT == counter)
            {
                cout<<"Limit reached";
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
            words[counter] = word;
            word = strtok(NULL," ");
            counter++;
        }
        if(flag)
        {
            break;
        }
    }while(counter>0);
    getchar();
}
```

As of now, this program has the limit to accept only 5 words and put it in a string array.

Comment: What if the user inputs a string that IS 300 chars long? What will happen in your program?

Comment: @RedX changed it from char array to string.

Answer (score 0):

Following will read only `count` no words separated by spaces in a vector, discarding
others.

Here punctuations are also read as "word" is separated by spaces, you need to remove them from vector.

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
int count=1000;
std::copy_if(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin), 
             // can use a ifstream here to read from file
             std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
             std::back_inserter(v),
             [&](const std::string & s){return --count >= 0;}
            );
```

Comment: how will you handle line inputs which has multiple words??

Comment: Above will do, all inputs should be separated by space. The default `istream_iterator` with just wait for EOF

Answer (score -2):

Use the following function:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You can specify the third argument to limit the amount of read characters.

Comment: That's a Windows API, not a C++ function, and the OP wants to read a fixed number of words, not fixed number of characters